# cannot read a file from META-INF

Tags: java

I have a big issue doing something really stupid. That is to say open a stream to a resource file in my META-INF folder. I am working on a jar tool and on doing this:

```
InputStream schemaIS = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/schema.xsd");
```

I simply get a null! The project is built using maven and the xsd file ends up in the META-INF folder, but it still won't work.

What I don't understand is the theory behind it? How do the ClassLoader execute the lookup in the file system? How do I get my hands on the file?

Comment: is it a web application?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try removing first slash:

```
InputStream schemaIS = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/schema.xsd");
```

You need a leading slash if you are calling the `getResourceAsStream` method on a `Class` object. On a `ClassLoader` object, the path is always absolute, and the leading slash is not necessary.

Comment: if it's a regular META-INF that resides on the root of the classpath, the leading slash is needed.

Comment: @Bozho leading slash is needed if you are calling getResourceAsStream method on a Class object, not on a classloader.

Comment: it is _not_ required if calling on the classloader, but certainly does not make a difference. What `class.gerResourceAsStream()` does is to resolve the path relative to itself, and then pass it to its classloader's getResourceAsStream.

Comment: @Bozho if you pass an absolute path to `class.getResourceAsStream`, it will strip off the leading slash **before** passing it to its classloader. The classloader simply doesn't work with leading slashes, IMO.

Comment: no leading slash... But, i had problems because i had something like "META-INF\resources/subdir/foo.bar" and the above failed (because of the backward slash?). after i changed all my slashes to forward slashes it worked ("META-INF/resources/subdir/foo.bar")

Answer (score 2):

try this path: `META-INF/schema.xsd` (first `/` omitted)