# Read properies file in META-INF from a jar

Tags: java, maven

I am trying access a properties file in a library. The problem is that the file is located in the META-INF folder of the application which is using my library. I am currently using:

`private static final String CONFIG_FILE = "config.properties";`

```
private Properties getConfigFile(){
    InputStream input = null;
    Properties config = new Properties();
    input = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_FILE);
    if(input == null){
        System.out.println("*****************************************INPUT NULL DEST**************************************");
        return null;
    }
    try {
        config.load(input);
        return config;
    } catch (IOException io) {
        if(input!=null){
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return config;
}`
```

But withoud any success. I have tried to rename the constant to "META-INF/config.properties" and still getting null.

Comment: Use a leading slash to specify an absolute path. This is in the api doc for Class.getResouceAsStream

Comment: Hello Nathan, 
I have tried all combinations with slashes and META-INF without getting any further

Comment: Meta-inf is just a directory. /META-INF/config.properties should work.

Comment: sadly it does not :/

Comment: /META-INF/file
META-INF/file
file
/file 
 and all with class and classLoader

Comment: Read the docs, get clarification from the linked so post, investigate the facts, and check your assumptions.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782088/cannot-read-a-file-from-meta-inf

Comment: From my investigation came out that you can not access files in META-INF from the client of the library even with getResourcesAsStream. Thanks for the smart advice.

Comment: Interesting, reopened and upvoted